# Two gaussian and linear curves

Tags: plotting, fitting, nonlinear

I wanted to fit two gaussian and linear curves, I tried to use nonlinear model fit, but I'm making somewhere a mistake.

I know that one gaussian curve can be fitted as

```
nlm1 = NonlinearModelFit[N@ToExpression[data], 
   a1*E^(-((x - max)^2/(2*b1^2))) + b1*x + c1, {a1, b1, c1}, x];
```

I wanted to get something like this: [image]

How it should be done?

Comment: Please post your data and some code about such figure.

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of MMA.SE start by taking the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now. It will help us to help you if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). In particular, don't make us guess what you have tried, please [edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/257812/edit) your question to include a **minimal working example** of the code you are using. Please use [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). As you receive give back, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data looks like it could be described with a linear trend plus two gaussian-shaped curves requiring 8 parameters:  2 for the linear trend and 3 for each gaussian-shape.  Your code only allows for the linear trend and one gaussian shape.

Here is some made-up data roughly in the form of what you show:

```
x = Range[1000]/1000;
parms = {a1 -> 0.7, a2 -> -0.6, a3 -> 0.5, a4 -> 0.04, a5 -> 0.5, 
   a6 -> 0.4, a7 -> 0.03, a8 -> 0.75};
y = (a1 + a2 x + a3 Exp[-(x - a5)^2/(2 a4^2)] + 
      a6 Exp[-(x - a8)^2/(2 a7^2)] /. parms) +
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.05], 1000];
data = Transpose[{x, y}];
ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1/2, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Fake data]

To get appropriate results from `NonlinearModelFit` you'll need to reasonable starting values for the gaussian shape parameters which you can get from looking at your data.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   a1 + a2 z + a3 Exp[-(z - a5)^2/(2 a4^2)] + a6 Exp[-(z - a8)^2/(2 a7^2)],
   {a1, a2, a3, {a4, 0.05}, {a5, 0.5}, a6, {a7, 0.1}, {a8, 0.7}}, z, MaxIterations -> 1000];
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> Large], 
 Plot[nlm[z], {z, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

But you'll need to look at the residuals to see if you're missing something in the error structure such as a non-constant variance or serial correlation.